# Find another process and click on user interface C#

Tags: c#, onclick, click, mouse, virtual

I need find another application process in Windows (another program which is running). When that process is runing I need to click on the button which is in that another program. That mechanism I must to create on C#. Can be used Console Application.

Which library can do it? Looking for an example?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - Aside from being unclear to me what you are asking, I am also not sure what you have already tried, where you are stuck, etc.

Comment: Elementary to understand what I'm looking for an example or library for C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can get a list of processes by calling [Process.GetProcesses()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netframework-4.7#System_Diagnostics_Process_GetProcesses).  The `Process` object has a property for the [MainWindowHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=netframework-4.7) of the process.  With that, you should be able to send mouse clicks to the process.  You can use the `SendMessage` method to send mouse down and mouse up calls.  The second parameter (lParam) is where you send the coordinates you want to click.  So if you want to click on the coordinates 25, 100 then you would combine the coordinates with a bit shift like this:

```
int y = 100;
int x = 25;
var coords = (y << 16) | x;
```

And then call it like this (where hWnd is the window handle for the process):

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, coords);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, coords);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SendMessage(
        int hWnd,               // handle to destination window
        int Msg,                // message
        int wParam,             // first message parameter
        int lParam);            // second message parameter


public const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I needed